# Data being sent to the wrong table when using Action Text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

Using Ruby on Rails 6, after the user saves their story(using Action Text to type their story), they will be redirected to the `show` view where the story can be read. However, nothing is showing up and when checking the database, nothing seems to be saved.

After going through the documentation and watching some videos, I removed the `body` column from my `Story` table to be stored by ActionText.

The model:

```rb
class Story < ApplicationRecord
    # declare that body has a rich text field
    has_rich_text :body
end
```

The controller:

```rb
def new
        @story = Story.new
    end

    def create
        @story = Story.new(params[:story_params])
        if @story.save
          redirect_to @story
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

    def story_params
        params.require(:story).permit(:heading, :summary, :body)
    end
```

The form from new.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_with(model: @story) do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :heading %> <br>
    <%= form.text_area :heading %>
    <br>
    <%= form.label :summary %> <br>
    <%= form.text_area :summary %> 
    <br>
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :body %>
    <br>
    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I expected the `heading` and `summary` to be stored in the Story table while ActionText handles the `body`.
Here's what [happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GassT.png) when creating and saving a story.
As seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O17yu.png), nothing is saved in the Story table.

Comment: "After going through the documentation and watching some videos, I removed the body column from my Story table to be stored by ActionText." I don't understand why did you do this? Where do you want this `body` content to be stored?

Comment: The `body` is the content of the story. Initially it was in the Story table as `body:text`. After learning that ActionText has its own table when watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJZ9TnKrt7Q&t=662s), I decided to let ActionText store the body by declaring `has_rich_text :body` in the Story model as it seemed to be the best practice.

Comment: Actually, you only show GET for show and no log for create. That might be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually use your `story_params` method:

```
@story = Story.new(story_params)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't copy-paste my code properly. Unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: @SamLee I noticed something else, so I edited my answer. Check this out please.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the problem, silly mistake.